# Corpus transformation to tree bank-like grammar

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling to get a good code for below transformation

From: `(S (S (pomp:stem) (ous:suffix)) (ly:suffix))`

To: `(S (S (STEM pomp) (SUFFIX ous)) (SUFFIX ly))`

Stem/suffix/prefix are standard terms while pomp/ous/ly will vary for each word. I have 1000+ such rows which needs to be transformed .
I tried regex match/findall with series of steps but not getting a clean results.
Is there a quick way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do:

```
import re
a = '(S (S (pomp:stem) (ous:suffix)) (ly:suffix))'
re.sub(r"(\w+):(\w+)",lambda x: x.group(2).upper()+' '+x.group(1),a)
'(S (S (STEM pomp) (SUFFIX ous)) (SUFFIX ly))'
```